# Не работает [^-] в регулярном выражении для проверки URL на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно создать регулярное выражение для проверки URL.

Мой код:

```js
var regForURL = /((http(s)?):\/\/)?[a-zA-Z\d@:%._\+~#=]{2,}[^-]\.[a-z]{2,}([-a-zA-Z\d@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/i;
var wrongURL_0 = 'http://www.domain-.com';
console.log('Is URL correct?\n1)' + regForURL.test(wrongURL_0));
```

Данный URL должен быть false так как перед точкой стоит тире, но он true.

Comment: Язык какой? Это же  js?

Comment: Да js. Извините что не написал(

Answer (score 1):

Оно работает. Просто Парсится немного не так, как Вы ожидаете.

```
[a-zA-Z\d@:%._\+~#=]{2,} парсит две первые ww
[^-] парсит третью w (все законно).
а дальше есть точка...
```

К тому же, Ваше выражение может парсить абсолютно невалидные url, например такое `http://@@@@@:@:@:@:.domain.com`.